# How can I make grep use CRLF (and not LF) as a newline?

Tags: macos, grep, newlines, crlf

I need to grep through a file where not only are lines terminated by a CRLF, but they might also have several LFs on each line.  How can I make grep ignore LFs unless there's a CR in front of them?  FYI, I'm using OS X, so it would be helpful to have BSD grep instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any way to do that using just `grep`, but you could use `perl`, e.g.,

```
perl -e '$/="\r\n";' -ne 'print if /your_pattern/;' your_filename
```

or you could use `tr` as a filter around `grep`, e.g.,

```
tr '\n\r' '\0\n' < your_filename | grep -a your_pattern | tr '\0\n' '\n\r'
```

The latter assumes that your file doesn't already contain any NULs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use awk instead. 
awk has RS (Records Seperator) variable to change the line terminator